# Identify an obstacle in front of the radar

Tags: radar

I use the K-LC6 24 GHz microwave module in the linear frequency-modulated signal mode to determine the distance to moving objects. But if I put a barrier in front of this radar while it is moving, I can determine it, but as soon as the object becomes motionless, I no longer see it. Is it possible to somehow determine the introduced barrier in front of the microwave module? At a distance of up to 0.5m or closer. That is, not just at the moment the barrier was introduced, but after the barrier remained and became stationary?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details. For instance, how are you processing the received data?

Comment: @ AnonSubmitter85 The output of the I microwave module, then an amplifier, then a band-pass filter (to cut off unnecessary spec and normalize the gain) and the ADC.

Comment: What about after the ADC? How are you performing the detection?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I pass the digitized signal through a series of filters and get the Doppler frequency.

Comment: Once there is no movement, the target is at zero Doppler. I am guessing that your detection algorithm ignores this frequency. What about range? Do you do any sort of range compression? Can your form a range/Doppler map and do your detection on that?

Comment: @ AnonSubmitter85 I do not understand. Can you explain in more detail? To detect motion, I use the Doppler frequency. My algorithm ignores frequencies in which there is no Doppler frequency.

Comment: Once there is no motion, the target is at zero Doppler. If you are ignoring this frequency, then you are ignoring the target.